# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'PDO' и 'mysqli' not found in

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, apache, mysqli

Хочу подсоединиться к mysql  -  не выходит.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'PDO' и 'mysqli' not found in

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "test";
$password = "test";

Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";
```

Пробовала по-разному всё время ошибка из заголовка. И в php.ini раскомментировала строчки для PDO и для mysqli, но толку мало.
Что делать?

Ubuntu 14.04
PHP:

```
if (!function_exists('mysqli_init') && !extension_loaded('mysqli')) {
    echo 'We don\'t have mysqli!!!';
} else {
    echo 'Phew we have it!';
}
```

выводит
Код (Text):

```
'We don't have mysqli!!!'
```

Comment: A где база данных по каторому надо подключится ?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysqli-connect.php
падает с той же ошибкой. Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect()

Comment: В ответе посмотри

Answer (score 0):

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "test";
$password = "test";


Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";

   $sql = "CREATE DATABASE test";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Database created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error creating database: " . $conn->error;
}
```

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'mysqli' not found

Comment: Теперь сново попробуй

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'mysqli' not found in

Comment: У тебя установлен  mysqli?

Comment: Вот и я думаю... Как проверить?

Comment: Ты на хосте или на  локалье?

Comment: >sudo apt-get install php7.2-mysqli

Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
Заметьте, вместо «php7.2-mysqli» выбирается «php7.2-mysql»
Уже установлена самая новая версия php7.2-mysql.

Comment: На локальном компьютере.

Comment: Используйте  xampp   3 в 1  apache ,php, mysql

Comment: вот сылка   https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html